# binding webHttpBinding not support Session?

Tags: wcf

Is Wcf Rest 'WebHttpBinding' Support 
`[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]` ?

I am getting null response of

```
OperationContext.Current.SessionId;
```

Answer (score 0):

change the `ServiceContract` attribute as :

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
```